# I can't do a foreign key, constraint error

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, octobercms

I'm having a commum error and I can't go over it, know as `[Illuminate\Database\QueryException]   SQLSTATE[42000]` here is the full error:

> [Illuminate\Database\QueryException]   SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error
>   or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check
>   the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the
>   right syntax to use near 'unsigned null' at line 1 (SQL: alter
>   table `files` add `slug` varchar(255)
>   unsigned null)

A separated error:

> [PDOException]   SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation:
>   1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'unsigned null' at line 1

He are the tables I'm trying to do the foreign key:

**Files**

```
  public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('files', function($table)
        {
            $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
            $table->increments('id')->unsigned();
            $table->string('name')->nullable();
            $table->boolean('enable_sch')->nullable();
            $table->datetime('schdate')->nullable();
            $table->string('flsize')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
        Schema::table('files', function($table)
        {
          $table->string('slug')->unsigned()->nullable();
          $table->foreign('slug')->references('slug')->on('slugs');
        });
    }
```

**Slugs**

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('slugs', function($table)
        {
            $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
            $table->string('nameslug');
            $table->string('slug')->unsigned()->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('slugs');
    }
```

What I'm trying to do is to add to the `files table` the `*slug column*` from the `slugs table`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I'm using OctoberCMS with Laravel, there are `relationships` like `$hasMany` and `$belongsTo` on the `**models** file`.

If are in trouble with this on OctoberCMS, just consult [this](https://octobercms.com/docs/database/relations)

Comment: Please avoid link only answer but quote the relevant part that was a solution for you.

Answer (score 3):

I guess `string` data type cannot be `unsigned()`, that's why you're getting an error.

Use this in both migrations:

```
$table->string('slug')->nullable();
```

Comment: Mhhh I change it to `$table->integer('slug')->nullable();` the error I was getting dispeared but I have another one ``[Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
  SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table 'october.#sql-3f9_3b' (errno: 150) (SQL: alter tab
  le `files` add constraint files_slug_foreign forei
  gn key (`slug`) references `slugs` (`slug`))``

Comment: Try to separate migrations. Temporarily remove `files` migration from the directory and run `php artisan migrate` command. Then move this migration back and run the command again.

Comment: Try to move `$table->string('slug')->nullable();` to the `Schema::create` clause. Then put `Schema::table` part where you're adding foreign key to a table into separate migration file. Run migration which will create table, then run migration which will add foreign key. Sometimes it works for me.

Comment: That works, but it's something wrong when I try to do the relation, but I dont know what...

Comment: I don't know if I can do these relations with a `string`, that might be the problem.